# Failing to AVRO serialise on only one consuming microservice

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have five Kafka consuming services and one Kafka producing service.  I am after rolling out a new avro schema in a consumer library in each of the Java consuming microservices. I have not made the producer side changes yet.  But one of the consuming services is failing to serialize anything the other four are working fine.

I get this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:122)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:69)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromPath(UriBuilder.java:111)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:656)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:642)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:217)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:291)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:276)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:273)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:97)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:87)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:62)
```

Some things that changed on both the producer side and consumer sides is the versions of
kafka-avro-serializer up to 6.0.0
kafka-clients up to 2.0.0

Then as a result the record that arrives at this consumer is null and in our configuration blocks our queue and we don't advance the manual offset.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the [**`jersey-client`**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client) library.

You can add the `.jar` manually or depending on your build tool:

**`Maven`**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**`Gradle`**

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '3.0.0'
```

**`SBT`**

```
libraryDependencies += "org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-client" % "3.0.0"
```

...

(...)